# Jquery select attribute != includes elements that don't have the attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select elements that do not match a given attribute id. Based on the following simplified example, why does $("td[groupId != 1]") return elements that do not even have the groupId attribute? Is there another way to select elements that have a groupId where the value is not 1?

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Group 1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1 - 1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1 - 2</td>
    <td groupId="1">1 - 3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td groupId="2">2 - 1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td groupId="3">3 - 1</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td groupId="2">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td groupId="3">3</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1</td>
    <td groupId="1">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td groupId="2">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td groupId="3">3</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$("td[groupId][groupId != 1]")`

This will select all td that have a groupId and then select all td in that set that do not have the value `1`.

PS. This is [documented behaviour](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeNotEqual#attributevalue) of the not operator.

Comment: From the docs: Matches elements that either **don't have the specified attribute** or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$("td[groupId][groupId!='1']")
```

[This type of selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeMultiple#attributeFilter1attributeFilter2attributeFilterN) matches all elements with the attribute `groupId`, but then only chooses the ones where the value is not `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following, first select all td's with groupId != 1 and then select those who have groupId specified from that jQuery set:

```
$('td[groupId!= 1]').filter('[groupId]');
```

IMHO this is perfectly logic, td's that do not have a groupId have a groupId that does not equeal 1, thus are added to the resultset. Or to put it in code:

```
var x = {};
typeof x.foo === 'undefined'; //true
x.foo !== 1; //true
```